# Finding a derivative that involves an integral that cannot be solved by elementary functions

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

How should I go about finding the value of integral in the image below. Is using the product rule, and the fundamental theorem of calculus the correct approach to finding the derivative? Thanks
[image]

Comment: sorry, I am new to this site. The image can be accessed by clicking on the words.

Comment: It's in that link itself..

Comment: Post it inline on the textbox..

Comment: I am not able to post images.

Comment: Yes, product rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus is the way to go. Trying to evaluate the integral is just stupid and masochistic.

Comment: However, following application of product rule, I still  need to find a way to evaluate the integral. Is there a way to further simplify the integral?

Comment: Thanks Dando18 so much  for helping to edit the post